# Blackberry AppWorld - Description language

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-world

I'm adding an application to AppWorld, and on the Description field I'm adding a spanish description (wich my application supports). 
The thing is that our app it only supports english since is targeted for a local market. Unfortunately it still asks me for English details of it (like descriptions), so my question is.... is it mandatory to provide an English descriptions? Even tho our app doesn't support (or will) support any other language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to include an English description, as it is mandatory regardless of the language the application runs in.

Why? Applications are not filtered by language like they can be by device model or OS. Since any device, regardless of language, can view or download the app, English is used as a default when a language-specific description doesn’t exist.

If your application is published in Spanish, I'd highly recommend to include a statement that explains fact in a brief English description, followed by a more detailed separate description of the application submitted in Spanish.